# C# Binding a Property but checking another

Tags: c#, binding

I'm trying to bind the `IsEnabled` property of a button.

```
IsEnabled="{Binding DisableButtonCheck}"
```

This property is inside my button- model:

```
    public bool DisableButtonCheck
    {
        get { if (Settings.Default.LockedButtons && DisableOnPatching) { return true; } else { return false; } }
    }
```

How could I make the binding listen to the change of the `Settings.Default` peroperty? 
Right now it listens to the `DisableButtonCheck` property.

Comment: I don't think that is solving my problem. I don't want to bind to the Settings.  Property. I want to bind the property nested in the model but also check if the Settings.Default property is true or not.

Comment: it says "so you just need to subscribe to PropertyChanged on Properties.Settings.Default and raise your own PropertyChanged in response". So you can react to change your property in the model

Comment: Well that helps. Thanks!